# How to find Average Battery Level used by the particular activity in android application

Tags: android, batterylevel

How to find the average battery level used by a particular activity in an android application?

Answer (score 0):

For this, you need to use [AppPulse Mobile](http://apppulse-help.saas.hpe.com/mobile/eng/Content/2_Getting_Started/top_nav_getting_started.htm).

For this you need to upload your APK, by this, you can monitor each operation happening in your app for example Battery usage of the particular device, screen, API calls time, crashes, performance etc..

For more info see here:

http://apppulse-help.saas.hpe.com/mobile/eng/Content/2_Getting_Started/top_nav_getting_started.htm